# Cake PHP custom validation rule

Tags: class, cakephp, validation

I got a problem with a custom validation rule in Cake 2.X

I want to check if the entered zipcode is valid and therefore a function in the class zipcode is called from the class post.

But the validation returns false all the time.

Appmodel in class post (rule-3 is it):

```
'DELIVERYAREA' => array(
        'rule-1' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 5, 5),
            'message' => 'Bitte eine fünfstellige Postleitzahl eingeben'
        ),
        'rule-2' => array(
            'rule' => 'Numeric',
            'message' => 'Bitte nur Zahlen eingeben'
        ),
        'rule-3' => array(
            'exists' => array(
                'rule' => 'ZipExists',
                'message' => 'Postleitzahl existiert nicht!'
            )
        )
    ),
```

Appmodel in class zipcode:

```
class Zipcode extends AppModel {
  var $name = 'Zipcode';

  var $validate = array(
    'zipcode' => array(
       'length' => array(
              'rule' => array('maxLength', 5),
              'message' => 'Bitte einen Text eingeben'
          ),
         'exists' => array(
          'rule' => array('ZipExists'),
          'message' => 'Postleitzahl existiert nicht!'

       )
    )         
  );

  function ZipExists($zipcode){

    $valid = $this->find('count', array('conditions'=> array('Zipcode.zipcode' =>$zipcode)));
    if ($valid >= 1){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I hope it´s something stupidly easy?
Thanks in advance

Comment: is length validation is working or not ?

Comment: I don´t know what you mean. Every other given rule works fine.

Comment: you should add "last=>true" to your length validation rule. no need to trigger db calls if the zipcode is of invalid length in the first place.

Comment: @mark: good point. I´ll try that. But to topic: The problem is that Cake says "could not find validation helper" blabla. I tried it now with validation from controller. Please see my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078182/cake-php-validation-error-not-shown-although-existing-in-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Cake wants the custom validation rules to be in the certain class where the rule is called. So, when you call a custom rule in class post, the custom function has to be written down in class post, otherwise cake won´t find it and validate it to false everytime.

The magic to do here is to import the appmodel-class you want to use in the class you call the validation-function. That works with the following statement:

$Zipcode = ClassRegistry::init('Class to use - in my case "Zipcode"');

But if your tables are associated with each other with hasAny or belongsTo and stuff, the custom function works without that. Another important point you mustn´t miss is, that all validation functions has to be introduced with "public function xyz" otherwise cake won´t find them too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

`'Zipcode.zipcode' =>$zipcode`

...needs to be this:

`'Zipcode.zipcode' =>$zipcode['zipcode']`

Comment: Nope, doesn´t work. The function ZipExists works fine because I call it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Careful what you expect inside the validation rule. Use debug() etc to find out what exactly is coming in. $data is always an array here.

```
public function zipExists($data) {
    $zipcode = array_shift($data); // use the value of the key/value pair
    $code = $this->find('first', array('conditions'=> array('Zipcode.zipcode' =>$zipcode)));
    return !empty($code);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that Cake says "could not find validation helper" blabla. I tried it now with validation from controller. Please see my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078182/cake-php-validation-error-not-shown-although-existing-in-array

Comment: what validation helper? note the casing, your validation method is supposed to be camelBacked `'rule' => 'zipExists',` then, as well.

Comment: The problem with the validation handler (sorry, I did mean handler rather than helper): Warning (512): Could not find validation handler ZipExists for DELIVERYAREA [CORE/Cake/Model/Validator/CakeValidationRule.php, line 277]. The corresponding code for that is (in Appmodel at DELIVERYAREA): 'rule-3' => array(
    'rule' => array('ZipExists'),
    'message' => 'Postleitzahl existiert nicht!'
   )

Comment: again - it should then be `zipExists` not `ZipExists` - you should be more careful with the casing. this is very important in many languages and some OS.

Comment: The error with the handler is still occurring when changed to zipExists :-(

Comment: The strange thing is that when called from controller the function ZipExists works completely as intended. Returns true or false like a charm. Please see the new question regarding that topic :)

Comment: because you cannot just call validation methods from outside. they are designed to work with validation! if you need both, you need to prep your methods accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I tried it with your code from above but it still says handler zipExists not found. Does Cake want to have the zipExists in the class post? Maybe you have an idea

Comment: I found a solution. Please look at my new answer

Answer (score 0):

try this for only model validation.

```
  function ZipExists(){

    $valid = $this->find('count', array('conditions'=> array('Zipcode.zipcode' =>$this->data['Zipcode']['zipcode'])));
    if ($valid >= 1){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that Cake says "could not find validation helper" blabla. I tried it now with validation from controller. Please see my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078182/cake-php-validation-error-not-shown-although-existing-in-array