# Cake PHP validation error not shown although existing in array

Tags: php, cakephp, validation

After having trouble with calling validation functions in the Model, I tried with validating from controller. That works fine except one field which value is wrong is not shown red and doesn´t show the error-message.

The "validationErrors"-array passed to the view looks like this:

```
array(
'CITY' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Bitte eine Stadt angeben'
),
'CART' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Bitte etwas eingeben'
),
'DATE' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Bitte das Datum eingeben'
),
'TIME' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Bitte die Zeit eingeben'
),
'INCOME' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Bitte das Trinkgeld in Euro angeben'
),
'DELIVERYAREA' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Postleitzahl existiert nicht!'
)
)
```

The "DELIVERYAREA" is built in dynamically with this code:

```
//form errors formatieren für plz-validierung
            $this->Post->set($this->request->data['Post']);
            $this->Post->validates();
            $errors = $this->Post->validationErrors + $this->Zipcode->validationErrors;

            //in $errors die keys ZIPCODE und DELIVERYAREA anlegen und zipcode löschen
            if ($this->request->data['Post']['B/S'] == 'S' && !isset($errors['ZIPCODE'])) {
                $errors['ZIPCODE'] = $errors['zipcode'];
            };
            if ($this->request->data['Post']['B/S'] == 'B' && !isset($errors['DELIVERYAREA'])) {
                $errors['DELIVERYAREA'] = $errors['zipcode'];
            };
            unset($errors['zipcode']);
            debug($errors);
            $this->set('validationErrors', $errors);
```

The problem is that all fields are showing red with their certain message except the DELIVERYAREA-one which I find strange ...
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I got back to validate within appmodel which is more consistent.

Cake wants the custom validation rules to be in the certain class where the rule is called. So, when you call a custom rule in class post, the custom function has to be written down in class post, otherwise cake won´t find it and validate it to false everytime.

The magic to do here is to import the appmodel-class you want to use in the class you call the validation-function. That works with the following statement:

$Zipcode = ClassRegistry::init('Class to use - in my case "Zipcode"');

But if your tables are associated with each other with hasAny or belongsTo and stuff, the custom functions works without that. Another important point you mustn´t miss is, that all validation functions has to be introduced with "public function xyz" otherwise cake won´t find them too.